# Is it a good idea to persist a timer in local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is it in any way bad to persist a constantly changing timer in the localstorage?

Basically i have a timer and a function which looks at the count so every time a second passes the localstorage item is updated to the new one.

Comment: since the data is saved to internal storage, that can drain battery and wear flash. You can save it onbeforeunload, so you don't need to save it all the time. Session-storage might be a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of the time rate, every second is ok, I have used this solution once and never had any problem, but if it's lower than 1s, you should find another solution.